# Delete a div with the right mouseclick (block contextmenu)

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, right-click

i have a problem with the right-click-contextmenu

i try to delete a div

```
$(".global_class").live('mousedown', function(e)
{
    if( (e.which == 3) ) 
    {
       // $('#'+this.id+'').remove();
       del_function(this.id);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}).live('contextmenu', function(e){  e.preventDefault(); });
```

This code works but the problem is the `$('#'+this.id+'').remove();` 
jquery removes the div and the live `$(".global_class").live('mousedown', function(e)` didn't start (result -> the context menu will not be blocked).

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the elements that are involved in an event, results in terms of bubbling and defaults and such get a bit squirrelly (even without jQuery's `live` being involved). You could do this:

```
$(".global_class").live('mousedown', function(e)
{
    var id = this.id;

    if( (e.which == 3) ) 
    {
       setTimeout(function() {
            del_function(id);
       }, 0);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}).live('contextmenu', function(e){  e.preventDefault(); });
```

...so that you remove the `div` *immediately after* the event finishes, rather than during the event.

---

Off-topic, but you can't cancel the `contextmenu` event on all browsers (Opera comes to mind), which you may want to factor into your UI decisions...

Comment: Thanks, works! <br />@off-topic, are you sure? It works on my Opera 10 browser?

Comment: @Peter: Oh good. I'd heard they were thinking of allowing that (I'm fairly sure Opera 9 didn't). Just checked in my copy, and it's a Preferences setting, so it may not be reliable (although I can't imagine many people would change it).